# generating call graph using Parserwalker Listener Vs visitor?

Tags: c++, parsing, grammar, antlr4

After reading **the definition antlr v4 book** , I understood there are two tree-walking mechanisms.

I want to generate SIMPLE call graph for Cpp grammar.

[this](http://uploadkon.ir/fl/d/ODIxMDQ%3D) is Cpp14 grammar.

here is part of rules:

```
postfixexpression
:
    primaryexpression           #PrimaryEX
    | postfixexpression '[' expression ']'      #label9
    | postfixexpression '[' bracedinitlist ']'      #label10
    | postfixexpression '(' expressionlist? ')'     #FuncCall
    | simpletypespecifier '(' expressionlist? ')'   #label11
    | typenamespecifier '(' expressionlist? ')'     #label13
    | simpletypespecifier bracedinitlist        #label14        
    | typenamespecifier bracedinitlist      #label15
    | postfixexpression '.' Template? idexpression  #label16        
    | postfixexpression '->' Template? idexpression #label17
    | postfixexpression '.' pseudodestructorname        #label18
    | postfixexpression '->' pseudodestructorname   #label19    
    | postfixexpression '++'            #label20
    | postfixexpression '--'            #label21
    | Dynamic_cast '<' typeid '>' '(' expression ')'    #label22
    | Static_cast '<' typeid '>' '(' expression ')' #label23
    | Reinterpret_cast '<' typeid '>' '(' expression ')'    #label24
    | Const_cast '<' typeid '>' '(' expression ')'  #label25
    | Typeid '(' expression ')'             #label26
    | Typeid '(' typeid ')'         #label27
```

my solution is using visitor and creating label for all rules which are necessary to find out the function name.

for example when I enter input file t.mainCpp

```
static void nastaran(int a, int b)
{
}
int main()
{
    a=func();
}
```

the parser tree is :

[image]

and I think for getting name of every function which is called in the code ,  need to find this sub-tree :

[image]

I mean I override visitor for label FunCall and get identifier value by calling postfixexpression's childeren visitors.
but I don't know if this solution is correct or suitable for this problem or not.should I use visitor ?

Comment: If this is what you are going to do, you might as well search for strings of the form  *identifier()*;its easier and gives an equally bad answer.   This fails to distinguish the same method name from two different methods, methods qualified by paths, and methods called via virtual methods. If you pick out *idexpression()* you might end up with qualified paths, but you still can't distinguish two identified qualified paths in separate namespaces.   You can't really do this with resolving the meaning of names. See my discussion of "LifeAfterParsing" in my bio.

Comment: yes I had read LifeAfterParsing before , it is all about DMS tool and I don't want to use it .@IraBaxter  I my self want to implement that.

Comment: Its  key point is that you  usually cannot avoid building a lot more machinery than "just the parser" to do almost anything.  You are welcome to build alll of that "life beyond parsing" yourself; just don't expect it to be a short, easy process, which is what you seem to propose in this question.

Comment: @IraBaxter Can I speed up process of creating call graph by using ASM library ? Actually I can't buy DMS tool.

Comment: "ASM library"  What is that, and why do you think it would "speed up" the process?  I note your interest is in doing this for C++, which is probably the world's hardest language to parse let alone do "life beyond parsing" activities.   i'd worry about the fact that you probably can't afford the effort to do this by yourself.

Comment: @IraBaxter http://asm.ow2.org/ it explains about ASM , you should consider I dont want to implement something perfect,actually I just want to impelement CHA algorithm , and if I have time i'll implement other algorithms

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you don't have the technical background to understand what you are asking to do.  Offering ASM as an option provides evidence; it is only useful if your intention is to analyze Java (and there it would be of some help),  but up to this point your question appears to entirely about C++.  And ASM is completely useless for C++.   Look, go take a compiler class, then ask this question again. (You won't have to ask, actually).

Comment: As one starting point, you might take your C++ grammar, and try to parse something real with it.   Unless it is stunningly good (I think I would have heard of it),  it will probably fail when applied to real code, not toy examples.  Learning how it fails is going to be your first lesson in the difficulties of the project you want to undertake.